# aiohttp - Set a cookie and then redirect the user

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am writing a web server using the python aiohttp library.

How do I set a cookie and then redirect the user to another page in one response?

It's possible to redirect the user with `aiohttp.web.HTTPSeeOther`, but I can't find a way to attach cookies to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just set cookie value of the response.

```
import aiohttp
response = aiohttp.web.HTTPSeeOther(<location>)
response.cookies['test'] = '1'
return response
```

Comment: This worked, except I used the `set_cookie` function instead of accessing the cookie dictionary directly.

Comment: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.StreamResponse.cookies